# Identify correct MongoDB query from a log

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to **identify the query sent from a web application to MongoDB**, which I have locally installed.

My goal is to transform the query in such a way that would allow me to execute it directly from a MongoDB client. I already logged the following query:

```
2019-10-17T14:03:31.267+0200 I COMMAND  [conn150] command fact_main.file_objects command: aggregate { aggregate: "file_objects", pipeline: [ { $unwind: "$processed_analysis.software_components.summary" }, { $match: { virtual_file_path.885884fa4e7e3027c378119e5f53d7ee06221f3245c952d793c1d9bd851fef0e_23409011: { $exists: "true" } } }, { $group: { _id: "$processed_analysis.software_components.summary", additional_information: { $addToSet: "$_id" } } }, { $sort: { _id: 1 } } ], cursor: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("12e1cd2c-9de7-494c-a850-3b4142ead110") }, $db: "fact_main", $readPreference: { mode: "primaryPreferred" } } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:4010 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:31 nreturned:7 reslen:1237 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 66 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 33 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 33 } } } protocol:op_msg 38ms
```

At least, getting the first part of the query would help me a lot but I failed.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share what you have tried, so that someone can show the right way or correct in case there are issues with that.

Comment: That said, I will post an answer from what I could figure from the posted info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the aggregation query (and can be run from *mongo shell*). Make sure you are connected to the right *database* and the *read preference* option is set in case you are connecting to a *replica-set* (see notes below):

```
db.file_objects.aggregate( [ 
{ $unwind: "$processed_analysis.software_components.summary" }, 
{ $match: { 
   "virtual_file_path.885884fa4e7e3027c378119e5f53d7ee06221f3245c952d793c1d9bd851fef0e_23409011":  
    { $exists: "true" }
   }
}, 
{ $group: { 
        _id: "$processed_analysis.software_components.summary",
        additional_information: { $addToSet: "$_id" } 
    } 
}, 
{ $sort: { _id: 1 } } 
] )
```

*There are other details:*

- "fact_main" is the database, I think ($db: "fact_main").
- There is the *read preference* mentioned, `$readPreference: { mode: "primaryPreferred" } }` . This means the query is run against a *replica-set*. You can specify the read preference if you are running against the replica-set. Otherwise, if it is just a *standalone database*, you can ignore the option (I think). How do you set the read preference? Try this: `db.getMongo().setReadPref("primaryPreferred");`
- `planSummary: ...`, this is the query plan for the query executed. In case you want to run the query plan with the aggregation query you can use the following syntax: `db.collection_name.explain().aggregate( [ ... ] )`. This will not run the query, just the query plan. Also, see other `explain()` method's other *modes*.

Comment: You are absolutely right, "fact_main" is the database. Your query was successful, just quotion marks have been missing (I think because of the underscore):
`'virtual_file_path.885884fa4e7e3027c378119e5f53d7ee06221f3245c952d793c1d9bd851fef0e_23409011': `


Thank you very much! I had not worked with MongoDB before and I really spent a lot of time to get this query working - without any success. You saved my day!